# Determine all real numbers a so that function is continuous

Tags: limits

I'am solving this task and I am stuck on part of it.

The task says:

> Determine all real numbers $ 'a'  $  so that function is continuous, if $\ f(x) = x^asin(\frac{1}{x}) ,x != 0$ and $\ f(x) = 0 ,x = 0$

I tried to solve it like this:

If f(0) = 0, for function to be continuous lim( $ x^a sin(\frac{1}{x} $) ) = 0, when x approaches 0.

I don't know how to solve for a = 0 because $ 0^0  $ is indefinite form.

If a > 0. because $sin(\frac{1}{x}) $ must be [-1, 1] the expression will be 0, when x approaches 0. So a > 0 can be solution

but for a < 0 . I don't know how to solve for this. I tried to solve it like this. because when a < 0 is the same as a > 0 when $ (\frac{1}{x})^a sin(\frac{1}{x}) $ => $ ∞ * sin(\frac{1}{x}) $. Now $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ can be 0 and that would give me again indefinite form.

Can someone help me how to find if function is continuous for a = 0 and for a < 0 and is my explanation for a > 0 valid?

Comment: What is $x!=0$ ? Did you mean $x\ne0$?

Comment: For $a=0$ you can take $x^a=1$.  But for most other values of $a$ you have a problem when $x$ is negative

Comment: @Sep yes! I meant that

Comment: @Henry , Ok but that does not help me much because if x^a = 1, ( I understand that I made a mistake there because x will be close to 0 but will not be 0) how can I know when sin(1/x) will be 0

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $a$ must be an integer $(a \in \mathbb{Z})$, because if $a$ was not an integer number, the expression $x^a$ would be undefined for $x<0$.

If $a = 1,2,3,4,...$ is a strictly positive integer, then your function approaches $0$ for $x \to 0$ and is therefore continuous.

If $a = 0$, then your function continuously oscillates for $x \to 0$ and therefore its limit for $x \to 0$ does not exist and, as a result, the function is not continuous.

If $a = -1,-2,-3,...$ is a strictly negative integer, then the limit of your function for $x \to 0$ does not exist, since arbitrarily large values appear close to $0$, because the sine expression periodically takes values close to $1$, which then explode when divided by $x^a$. Therefore, your function is again not continuous in this case.

Comment: A function could be continuous even if it was undefined for an interval. Take $\ln(x)$ for instance.

Comment: This is of course true. However, I do not see how this relates to my answer.

Comment: You said at the beginning that $a$ must be an integer for $x^a$ to be defined for $x < 0$. This doesn't have to be the case, though.

Comment: $x^a$ is well defined if and only if $a = \frac{m}{n}$ in irreducible form and $n$ is odd.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated the way the OP defined his function suggests, that it is supposed to be defined on the whole real line IMO. Otherwise, why would he write $x \neq 0$ instead of, lets say, $x>0$.

Comment: I do not understand the last part, what you've meant ' with since arbitrarily large values appear close to 0, because the sine expression periodically takes values close to 1, which then explode when divided by $ a^2$ '

Comment: Lets say $x_0>0$ is close to $0$ and such that $\sin(1/x_0) = 1$. Then the function value $\sin(1/x_0)*x_0^{-a} = x_0^{-a}$ will be very big. The closer $x_0$ is to $0$, the bigger the function value will become. Since there is an infinite amount of such arguments $x_0$ in each neighbourhood of $0$, your function cannot converge if you pass the limit $x \to 0$.